# Spring Framework: Getting wrong object of processFormSubmission() due to multiple tab in browser

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

The problem of getting a wrong object is due to multiple tab of browser with this scenario:

1. Tab one contains TestBean data. Create a new tab and fill up form with different TestBean data (Same page with same controller but different data).
2. The first tab submits the form containing TestBean.

Expected Result in Controller: Get the data in Tab one.

Actual Result in Controller: Get the data in Tab two.

Below code is my controller's processFormSubmission():

```
public class TestFormController extends SimpleFormController {
    public ModelAndView processFormSubmission(HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response, Object command, 
         BindException errors) throws Exception {

         TestBean testBean = (TestBean) command;
         ...
    }
}
```

**What approach should I do to get the correct data?**